# Regex Help Needed-for matching specific string

Tags: java, regex

Subject text:

```
444410******1010
```

This is the regex which I am using:

```
[0-9]{6}(?:\*\*\*\*\*\*)(?:[0-9]{4})
```

I am wondering if there is a way to improve it.

Comment: Sure.  Give it a try, and if it doesn't work right, post it here and someone here will help you work out why.

Comment: I second what @DavidWallace says. If you show your work, you will be asking a much better and more specific question rather than a "please do my work for me" type question.

Comment: Are the stars repetition or you meant to show actual stars?

Comment: Hello david, its not that i havent tried. I tried it, this is the regex i formed [0-9]{6}(?:\*\*\*\*\*\*)(?:[0-9]{4}) and I am thinking if there a way to improve it. Dont just come into conclusion.

Comment: Prash: post that with your question as it's too important to bury in comments. Also show what results it gives you and how it's not working for you.

Comment: Hello Hover, I does matched the regex pattern. I am just wondering if there could be an alternative way which matches the given string for example the first 6 digits has to be number and the followed 6 chars has to * and the remaining 4 is a number.

Comment: @Mariano - you're not supposed to change the meaning of the question when you edit it. The main point of the question was that Prashanna was missing the backslashes.  Putting them in makes the question invalid.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did not. Check the revision history. The problem was with `\*` not rendering correctly without the code formatting

Comment: @Mariano thanks for correcting the text in the post.

Comment: @Mariano - my apologies.  I see what you mean.  I thought Prashanna's problem was not being able to get a working regular expression, and that the missing backslashes were the reason.  On that note, I have removed my answer.

Comment: @PrashannaNarayanasamy No problem! Next time, when you're adding a string, a regex or code, use code formatting ;) ... It's the `{ }` button in the editor (or add 4 spaces at the begginingof the line)

Comment: @DavidWallace No worries. Been there, done that

Comment: Thank you. will use code formatting in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need non-capturing groups, and you might find `\d` more readable than `[0-9]`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}\\*{6}\\d{4}");
```